# How do I change text color when navigation link is selected? SwiftUI Mac Catalyst

Tags: swift, xcode, list, uitableview, swiftui

I have used a `List` of `NavigationLink` to generate my sidebar but when running as a Mac Catalyst app all selections use the system accent color as their background. This is fine but where the colour is dark I want the text to invert to white like it does in most Mac apps.

Can anyone help? Here's my code:

```
 List {
            
            ForEach(topics, id: \.self) { topic in
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(selectedDate: self.titles[topic])
                ) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(topic)
                            Text(self.titles[topic]!)
                }
                 
                }
            
            }
           
            
    }
```

Btw `topic` is an array of strings which are the keys for the dictionary `titles`. Thanks in advance.

[image: Sidebar]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the new `Label(_:)` element, instead of a custom HStack with image + text? Swift "2" now has `Label` which when coupled with the `SidebarListStyle` *should* do what you want to. Text goes to highlighted color when selected. Since you're using custom images, I'm not sure what happens there, but give it a try.

Instead of:

```swift
HStack {
  Image(...)
  Text(...)
}
```

Just use:

```swift
Label("Formalism", image: "formalism.png")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I haven't installed the Beta yet, I will download and try this.

Comment: I've now downloaded the Xcode 12.0 Beta 4 but I don't have Big Sur installed, so I can't test this yet, because `Label` requires a higher level of Mac Catalyst (14.0). Thanks again for your answer, I will return to this question once I have upgraded and if it solves the problem I will mark this as the solution..